# Transfer accounts from Mac or iPhone to new iPad?

Tags: iphone, accounts

I have 8 different email accounts configured on my iPhone. It's a pain to move them one-by-one to the iPad. If I wipe the iPad I can move them all over at the same time. Is there any way to do this without wiping the iPad? I just got a new email account and don't want to manually configure each device.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure what you mean: if you use the same Apple ID on both devices and you have enabled iCloud storage for keychain, mail, whatever else on the iPhone - assuming that it’s holding all the data you want on the iPad - you’re done.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.